# Android ParseQueryAdapter always empty

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-parsequeryadapter

I am trying to get data from Parse.com, and followed instrucions and examples on their site, but i run into problem i can't seem to fix.
Requested query is always empty. I use following code

```
public void createParseQuery(final int markerId){
ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<CommentPost> queryAdapterFactory =
    new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<CommentPost>() {
        public ParseQuery<CommentPost> create() {
        ParseQuery<CommentPost> parseQuery = CommentPost.getQuery();
        parseQuery.whereEqualTo("markerId", markerId);
        parseQuery.include("comment"); //comment define
        parseQuery.include("rating");
            return parseQuery;
        }
    };
    queryAdapter = new ParseQueryAdapter<CommentPost>(this, queryAdapterFactory) { 
        @Override
        public View getItemView(CommentPost post, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup){
            if (view == null) {
                view = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.item_comment_post, null);
            }
            TextView textViewPostUsername = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewPostUsername);
            TextView textViewPostComment = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewPostComment);
            RatingBar ratingBarPostRating = (RatingBar) view.findViewById(R.id.ratingBarPostRating);
            textViewPostUsername.setText(post.getUser().getUsername());
            textViewPostComment.setText(post.getComment());
            ratingBarPostRating.setProgress(post.getRating());
            return view;
        }
    };
    Boolean adapterEmpty= queryAdapter.isEmpty();
    Log.i("DEBUG","Adapter is empty "+adapterEmpty);
    ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView111);
    lv.setAdapter(queryAdapter);
}
```

Here adapterEmpty always returns "true", and listView isn't updated.

CommentPost class:

```
@ParseClassName("data")
public class CommentPost extends ParseObject {
ParseUser user;
int markerId;
String comment;
int rating;
public CommentPost() {
    super();
}
public String getComment() {
    return getString("comment");
}
public ParseUser getUser() {
    return getParseUser("user");
}
public int getRating() {
    return getInt("rating");
}
public void setComment(ParseUser user, int markerId, String comment,
        int rating) {
    put("user", user);
    put("markerId", markerId);
    put("comment", comment);
    put("rating", rating);
}
public static ParseQuery<CommentPost> getQuery() {
    return ParseQuery.getQuery(CommentPost.class);
}
}
```

When i do this code (from tutorial on Parse website):

```
mainAdapter = new ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject>(this, "data");
mainAdapter.setTextKey("comment");

ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView111);
lv.setAdapter(mainAdapter);
```

it's working fine, I am getting all saved comments for class "data", but i need customised query.
Any help would be greatly appreciated:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it to work. Here's the code:

```
public void createParseQuery(final int markerId) {

    ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<CommentPost> queryAdapterFactory = 
            new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<CommentPost>() {
        public ParseQuery<CommentPost> create() {
            ParseQuery<CommentPost> parseQuery = CommentPost.getQuery();
            parseQuery.whereEqualTo("markerId", markerId);
            parseQuery.include("user");
            parseQuery.orderByDescending("createdAt");

            return parseQuery;
        }
    };

    queryAdapter = new ParseQueryAdapter<CommentPost>(this, queryAdapterFactory) {
        @Override
        public View getItemView(CommentPost post, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (view == null) {
                view = View.inflate(getContext(),
                        R.layout.item_comment_post, null);
            }
            TextView textViewPostUsername = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.textViewPostUsername);
            TextView textViewPostComment = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.textViewPostComment);
            RatingBar ratingBarPostRating = (RatingBar) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.ratingBarPostRating);

            textViewPostUsername.setText(post.getUser().getUsername());
            textViewPostComment.setText(post.getComment());
            ratingBarPostRating.setProgress(post.getRating());
            return view;
        }
    };
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code, it helped me alot with a similar problem I have had